# C# Сравниваю две одинаковые строки и выдает false

Tags: c#, строки, ip, udp, c#-7.3

Отправляю с сервера который работает на *UdpClient* sqlite3 файл, на клиенте нужно проверить является ли файл sqlite3 формата.Первые 16 байтов этого формата в консоли выглядят вот так : "SQLite format 3". Почему 16 байтов если char символов 15? И при сравнении с такой же строкой выдает false. Сравнивал и через String.Equals и через "==".

```
 public static bool isResponseSQLiteFormat(byte[] bytes)
        {
 ///
            /// Takes first 16 bytes of array and convert it into string. This bytes contains file format
            /// if it's sqlite3.
            ///

            byte[] bytesWithFileFormat = new byte[16];
            for(int index = 0; index < 16; index++)
            {
                bytesWithFileFormat[index] = bytes[index];
            }
            /// Does not return true if string equals value here |
            ///                                                  v

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesWithFileFormat).Equals("SQLite format 3 ");
        }
```

Comment: какая строка возвращается в результате `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesWithFileFormat)`? в ней точно в конце пробел стоит?

Comment: https://ibb.co/sWSZYnn Вот ссылка на вывод в консоли через foreach каждый символ

Comment: вывод в консоль не показывает что за пробельный символ. Посмотри коды символов и коды символов исходной строки. Сравни общую длину проверяемой строки и эталона

Comment: [The Database Header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_database_header). В конце null, не пробел.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, тогда уж не null,  а символ с кодом `0`

Comment: Действительно, в конце был 0(по таблице это null) Спасибо!